# how to set once a user select a date in one field can't able to pick less than in another field in flutter

Tags: flutter

[Blockquote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1Nhn.png)

how to set once a user select a date in one field can't able to pick less than in another field in flutter

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this gor the first date picker

```dart
DateTime? startDate = await showDatePicker(
           context: context,
           initialDate: DateTime.now(),
           firstDate: DateTime.now(),
           lastDate: DateTime(2100),
        );
```

Use this for the next datepicker

```dart
DateTime? endPickedDate = await showDatePicker(
           context: context,
           initialDate: startDate,
           firstDate: startDate,
           lastDate: DateTime(2100),
        );
```

If you notice you can see the initial date  of end date picker is the picked value from startDatePicker.

Also a best approach will be to use a date range picker